# start genymotion vm but without genymotion

Tags: android, virtual-machine, genymotion

I created a virtual machine by genymotion  successfully.

Now, I want to start a virtual machine directly on the virtual box without
    genymotion but I got the virtual box blank.

How can I get the android window display on the virtual machine output,not the black screen....
What I want is:

[image]

but I got this

[image]

Comment: So basically you want to start a Genymotion from a Virtual machine, right?